# function that removes spaces and tabs

Tags: c, c-strings

im trying to make a function that removes spaces and tabs from a given string except for the first tab or space in the string. when im using my function it removes the spaces and tabs except for the first one but it also removes the first letter after the first space or tab. 
for example > "ad ad  ad"> "ad dad" instead of "ad adad"
why is that?

```
void RemoveSpacetab(char* source) {
    char* i = source;
    char* j = source;
    int spcflg = 0;

    while(*j != 0) {
        *i = *j++;

        if((*i != ' ') && (*i != '\t'))
            i++;
        if(((*i == ' ') || (*i == '\t')) && (spcflg == 0)) {
            i++;
            spcflg = 1;
        }
    }
    *i = 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to sit down with a piece of paper and think this through. You say that if the first character is a space or tab, it should be kept? Then check for that *first*, and if so just skip over it. Then go into the copy-loop. And in the loop you just copy from`source` to `dest` (which is initialized to point to `source` before the loop), unless `*source` is a space or a tab in which case you simply do nothing. Increase `source` and `dest` to point to the next location for the copy. Iterate until `*source` is the string terminator. End loop and add terminator to `dest`. Done!

Comment: Maybe you have used Pascal / Delphi for long time. In C it is not necessary to use brackets in case like `if ( *i != ' ' && *i != '\t' )`.

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage`.  the variable 'i' is meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: this line: `while(*j != 0)` has a few problems.  Suggest: `for( char *j=source; *j; j++ )`   One of the problems is that 0 is a multibyte integer and `j` is a pointer to char.  The C feature 'implicit conversion' might save your code, but you should not rely on the compiler fixing mistakes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to separate your source and destination arrays as they will become different lengths. You could find the starting position before copying characters like this, lets say you pass the source and the length of the source as `char* source, int length` (you could also calculate the length of the source with `strlen(source)`, then your function could look like this:

```
int i = 0;
char* dest = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
// Increment i until not space to find starting point.
while (i < length && (source[i] == '\t' || source[i] == ' ')) i++;

int dest_size = 0;
while (i < length) {
    if (source[i] != '\t' && source[i] != ' ') {
        // Copy character if not space to dest array
        dest[dest_size++] = source[i];
    }
    i++;
}
dest[dest_size++] = 0; // null terminator
// Feel free to realloc to the right length with 
//   realloc(dest, dest_size * sizeof(char))
return dest;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by two `if` statements one after the other. Your `i` precedes `j` when you detect a space for first time.

**Explanation:**

In first cycle the `i` points to position 0 and `j` too. The `'a'` at position 0 will be overwritten with itself then `j` moves onwards to position `1`. Your first `if` block finds out that the character at position 0 is not a space and not a tab, so moves the `i` to position 1.

In second cycle the `'b'` will be overwritten with itself then `j` moves to position 2 which is a space. The first `if` finds out that `'b'` at position 1 is not a space and not a tab so moves the `i` to position 2. Now the second `if` finds out that the `i` points to a space for first time and moves it to the position 3 while `j` is still points to the position 2.

In third cycle the `'a'` at position 3 will be overwritten with the space at position 2 and `j` catches up with `i`.

A possible fix to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void RemoveSpacetab(char* source) {
    char* i = source;
    char* j = source;
    char spcflg = 0;

    while(*j != 0) {
        *i = *j++;
        if(*i == ' ' || *i == '\t') {
            if(!spcflg) {
                i++;
                spcflg = 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    *i = 0;
}

int main() {
    char my_string[] = "ad ad ad";
    RemoveSpacetab(my_string);

    printf("%s\n", my_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The `j` still points to the space after first `ab` but `i` is pointing to `a`" - `j` was increased by `*j++` so it's pointing to the `a` too.

Comment: My bad. +1 for you, that's exactly the problem.

Comment: I expanded my explanation because the previous one was a bit indistinct.